# Processing W3C css validator output with Violations

Tags: validation, continuous-integration, reporting, w3c

There are a lot more output formats for linters and validators than there are tools to parse them. I haven't been able to find any tools that can parse the output of the canonical CSS and HTML validators provided by the W3C themselves. The output formats provided by the W3C CSS validator are documented in the [User Guide](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/manual.html#requestformat) (including one undocumented output format enabled with just `--format=xml`). Are there any tools (such as a Jenkins plugin) that can process any of the formats output by the W3C CSS Validator into a graph or other human-consumable report format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know. But I did write [an XSLT](https://github.com/kojiromike/ci/blob/master/css-validator-to-csslint.xsl) that converts the output of `java -jar css-validator --format=soap12` into the same format as [csslint](http://csslint.net/), which [Violations](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Violations) can process.

The validator itself always outputs its options above the XML, so you have to trim that off before you can transform it:

```
java -jar css-validator --format=soap12 "$someFile.css" |
    tail -n +1 | # GNU tail, or use some other way of trimming the first line
    xsltproc css-validator-to-csslint.xsl -
```

I hope someone finds this useful.